# ReactJS/Firestore: how to add sub-collection to existing firestore document

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a new collection in an existing firestore document :

Here is my firestore :

[image]

I'd like to create the "general" collection automaticaly.

Here is my code :

```
function App() {
  const dataGeneral = {
  email: "",
  firstname: "",
  lastname: "",
  phone: "",
  gdpr: false,
};

useEffect(() => {
  const migrateData = async () => {
    const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "users"); //gets the root collection
    const { idUser } = await addDoc(usersCollectionRef, {}); // Creates a new document in the root collection

    const usersSubCollectionGeneralRef = collection(db,`users/${idUser}/general`); //Creates a sub collection in the just created document

    const { idGeneral } = await addDoc(usersSubCollectionGeneralRef, { dataGeneral }); //Creates a document in the newly created collection

   };
   migrateData();
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? `addDoc(collectionRef, data)` looks good to me. Just not sure why you destructure `idUser` and `idGeneral` though - they don't exist on it, you probably mean `id`.

Comment: The problem is that the sub collection is not created, I added "general" manualy for the explaination but i need to create it via code

Comment: That's simple: you don't. Firestore cannot have empty collections, hence you can't create one. If you add a document to a non-existing collection, it does create the collection for you. If you delete the last document from a collection, it gets automatically deleted. You create a collection by adding the first document to it.

Comment: I see, How can I do that ?

Comment: Do what? Adding a document to a collection? You did it twice in your sample code, with `addDoc`.

Comment: Well no, that code doesn't work, it does create a new document in users but it doesnt create a collection (or should i say a new document) INSIDE de created document

Comment: [Check the docs, it does](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document). I would advice that you provide either more detail (error logs, etc) or you rephrase your question on what you want to achieve. Your first `addDoc` call creates an empty document in collections `users`, the second `addDoc` call creates a document in sub-collection `general` of that document you've created before. However, as pointed out in the first comment `idUser` doesn't exist. So your ref is probably off; again, debug your steps, log your return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to add sub-collection to existing firestore document

You don't add sub-collection explicitly, since Firestore cannot have empty collections. Instead sub-collections will be added automatically when adding a document to a collection. (And also deleted automatically if they don't hold any documents anymore)

That being said, your code destructures `idUser` and `idGeneral` from objects where those properties don't exist. You probably want to access the property `id` like this:

```js
// Create a new, empty document in `users`
const usersRef = collection(db, 'users');
const user = awaitDoc(usersRef, {
  data: 'new document in users'
});

// Create a new document in sub-collection `general`
const generalRef = collection(db, `users/${user.id}/general`);
const general = awaitDoc(generalRef, {
  data: 'new document in sub-collection general'
});
```

Your intention might have been to rename the destructured property. If that's the case, [see MDN for how to do that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring).

```js
const {id: idUser } = await addDoc(...)
console.log('id of new document: ', idUser)
```