# Fetching data using queries in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch data using queries from Firebase to paginate it afterwards.

My database is structured like this:

```
chats(collection):
  documentId(document)
    messages(array):[
            date,
            text,
            id,
   ]
```

And the thing is, while using:

```
const docRef = doc(db, 'chats', chatId); // chatId holds my documentId
 useEffect(() => {
  const getChats = async () => {
   const data = await getDoc(docRef);
      chatsMessages([...doc.data().messages])
}
getChats()},[])
```

gets the job done, and returns my data, I don't know how to limit the messages that I fetch, for example I'd want to fetch only 15 messages at first and after certain event fetch 15 more.

So I thought, the only way is using a query and get the job done with limit, orderBy, startAt,startAfter but I can't find anything on their docs that could help me point to my data in the way its structured.

I've been trying to use `const q = query(collection(db,'chats', chatId))` as a reference, but it doesn't work.

or

```
const q = query(collection(db,'chats') where ("Document ID", "==", chatId)).`
```

I've tried using their docs but there isn't any example to help me retrieve the data in the way it's structured in my database.

Comment: Solved, I just tweaked a bit my data, so Instead of an array with messages, I just created another collection (messages collection ) with documents ( a document for each message) and inside the document -> date, text, id ( no more array ).

Here is a reference that helped me with this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783001/reactjs-firestore-how-to-add-sub-collection-to-existing-firestore-document